# Primary color default value after angular update from 13 to 16

Tags: css, angular, sass

I updated my angular (+material-ui) system from 13 to 16. I have one problem: the value of the primary color of my custom theme doesn't work anymore. Its using the default value blue now.
I added the "@use "@angular/material" as mat;" and the values for typography and density, because I got some build warnings after I updated the angular version.

Here is my custom-theme.scss:

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

$my-orange: mat.define-palette(
  mat.$pink-palette,
  (
    50: green,
    100: green,
    200: green,
    300: green,
    400: green,
    500: green,
    600: green,
    700: green,
    800: green,
    900: green,
    A100: green,
    A200: green,
    A400: green,
    A700: green,
  )
);

$my-accent: mat.define-palette(
  mat.$blue-grey-palette,
  (
    50: white,
    100: white,
    200: white,
    300: white,
    400: white,
    500: white,
    600: white,
    700: white,
    800: white,
    900: white,
    A100: white,
    A200: white,
    A400: white,
    A700: white,
  )
);

$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, 500);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-grey-palette, A200, A100, A400);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $my-primary,
      accent: $my-accent,
    ),
    typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
    density: 0,
  )
);

@function theme() {
  @return $my_theme;
}
```

I import the custom in the styles.scss:

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
@use "./custom-theme";

@include mat.core();

@include mat.all-component-themes(custom-theme.theme());
```

When I run npm run start I get the following error messages:
1.

```
Undefined function.
   ╷
   │ @include mat.all-component-themes(custom-theme.theme());
   │                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src/styles.scss 19:35  root stylesheet
```

2. 

```
(50: #80ba24, 100: #80ba24, 200: #80ba24, 300: #80ba24, 400: #80ba24, 500: #80ba24, 600: #80ba24, 700: #80ba24, 800: #80ba24, 900: #80ba24, A100: #80ba24, A200: #80ba24, A400: #80ba24, A700: #80ba24) isn't a valid CSS value.
   ╷
   │   @error 'Hue "' + $hue + '" does not exist in palette. Available hues are: ' + map.keys($palette);
   │          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_theming.scss 47:10  -get-color-from-palette()
  node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_theming.scss 70:14  define-palette()
  src/custom-theme.scss 3:13                                       root stylesheet
```

Comment: Do you still use the legacy component?

Comment: No, I replaced all of the legacy components with the new ones manually. I updated the styles.scss file and updated it in the description.

Comment: Your primary palette is incomplete. You need to also define values for 100, 200, ... 900. I am surprised this ever worked. See more details on how to properly set up a palette in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#create-your-own-palette)

Comment: Oh sorry, the values are defined but I didn't post them to keep it simple. Didn't know it's that important. I updated the custom theme. Now it's 1:1.

Comment: Why do you define two light themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice a few mistakes:

1. You must not use `@include mat.core()` more than once according to [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#:%7E:text=The%20core%20mixin%20must%20be%20included%20exactly%20once%20for%20your%20application%2C%20even%20if%20you%20define%20multiple%20themes.%20Including%20the%20core%20mixin%20multiple%20times%20will%20result%20in%20duplicate%20CSS%20in%20your%20application.).
2. The use of `@import` is discouraged according to [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import/#:%7E:text=The%20Sass%20team,import%20rule%20instead.). Use `@use` instead.
3. You never executed the `all-component-themes` mixin to apply your custom theme to all components.

---

##### _custom-theme.scss

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, 500);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-grey-palette, A200, A100, A400);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $my-primary,
   accent: $my-accent,
 ),
 typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
 density: 0,
));

@function theme() {
  @return $my_theme;
}
```

##### style.scss

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use './custom-theme';

@include mat.core();

@include mat.all-component-themes(custom-theme.theme());
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to apply your code pieces to my project but I get some errors. I updated the question. Do you have an idea how to fix it? If it's too hard, I should think about building a new custom theme with the new mat-ui 16 guidelines instead of update this theme.

Comment: @JukeboxHero The first error is related to location of your `custom-theme.scss` file. You need to import it using the right path. Is it under `src` ?

Comment: @JukeboxHero Also, comment out all your code except my code and see if it works. Then you can start putting your code back.

Comment: The problem is somewhere around the import of the custom theme. I added "$ioo-text-color: red;" to the /src/custome-theme.scss file. Then I tried to use the value of ioo-text-color and I got the error message "undefined variable". So I think there is a weird problem with import the custom-theme.scss to the app. The custom-theme.scss has a reference in the angular.json "styles". I tried many things from google but I can't solve the problem right now.

Comment: @JukeboxHero The issue you are getting is out of scope. Please create a new question with issue and all the attempts you've tried and post a link here.